# 2DTransform speed. Matrix vs. translate,rotate,scale

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

Is it slower to calculate matrix in javascript and feed into transform property
 or should I use translate, rotate scale ? I find it easier to go with first, specially for SVG-animations, due origin-problems but the speed is important because of animation loop. I guess sin and cos are expensive but does it affect performance significally ?

```
function matrix_tsr(cx,cy,tx,ty,sx,sy,a){

    var sin = Math.sin(a);
    var cos = Math.cos(a);

    var m = [sx *cos,
            sy * sin, 
            -sx * sin, 
            sy * cos, 
             (-cx * cos + cy * sin + cx) * sx + tx, 
            (-cx * sin - cy * cos + cy) * sy + ty];

    return 'matrix('+m.join(',')+')';
} 

//Inside loop

var matrix = matrix_tsr( originX, originY, transX, transY, scaleX, scaleY, angle);

SVGelement.setAttribute('transform',matrix);

//insted of 
SVGelement.setAttribute('transform','translate(x,y),bla...');

//loop end
```

Comment: try it and see. Either the UA does sin and cos (probably in C++) or you do in javascript (which probably still calls out to a  C++ implementation under the hood somewhere)

Comment: In general native code would run faster (not a certainty today though) but in this case providing fixed values could turn out to be faster as setting a matrix doesn't involve any calculation in the matrix itself. Each translate, rotate etc. will do a matrix multiplication for each operation which in sum could under-perform compared to doing the calculation once in optimized/bin-code JS. But you need to do a test to find out...